# Vue nested v-for, get index of parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a nested `v-for`, basically, I want to get the index of the parent `v-for` and use it inside the child `v-for`

```
<template v-for="(branch, index) in $store.state.agency.branch_users.users">
    <table  class="table" id="agency-contact-table" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th aria-colindex="1" class="">#</th>
                <th aria-colindex="1" class="">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-if="branch.role_users" v-for="(branch_users, index) in branch.role_users">
                <td>{{$parent.$index}}</td>
                <td>{{branch_users.user.first_name}} {{branch_users.user.last_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

I tried using `$parent.$index` but it still doesn't work. It doesn't show any errors but no data also.
What should I do to get the `index` in my parent v-for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define the other index with another name, or name the first as `parent_index`

```
<template v-for="(branch, parent_index) in $store.state.agency.branch_users.users">
    <table  class="table" id="agency-contact-table" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th aria-colindex="1" class="">#</th>
                <th aria-colindex="1" class="">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-if="branch.role_users" v-for="(branch_users, index) in branch.role_users">
                <td>{{parent_index}}</td>
                <td>{{branch_users.user.first_name}} {{branch_users.user.last_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Comment: wow, thanks mate. I didn't thought of that. I thought `index` is the default in vue. I have been searching on how to add `alias` for `index` in v-for. lol

Comment: It is just a variable and you define the name for it